# Iterate sequentially over a dask bag

Tags: dask, concurrent.futures, dask-distributed

I need to submit the elements of a very large `dask.bag` to a non-threadsafe store, ie I need something like

```
for x in dbag:
    store.add(x)
```

I can not use `compute` since the bag is to large to fit in memory.
I need something more like `distributed.as_completed` but that works on bags, which `distributed.as_completed` does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably continue to use normal compute, but add a lock

```
def commit(x, lock=None):
    with lock:
        store.add(x)

b.map(commit, lock=my_lock)
```

Where you might create a `threading.Lock`, or `multiprocessing.Lock` depending on the kind of processing you're doing

If you want to use as_completed you can convert your bag to futures and use as_completed on them.

```
from distributed.client import futures_of, as_completed
b = b.persist()
futures = futures_of(b)

for future in as_completed(futures):
    for x in future.result():
        store.add(x)
```

You can also convert to a dataframe, which I believe does iterate more sensibly

```
df = b.to_dataframe(...)
for x in df.iteritems(...):
    ...
```